# Custom Checkbox with after element - not centreing reliably

Tags: html, css, sass

JSFiddle, won't work in Stack Snippet for some reason:
https://jsfiddle.net/m3aoswyx/2/

I have a custom checkbox, like this:

```
<label for="name" class="customCheckboxLabel">
        <input type="checkbox"  name="name" class="customCheckboxInput" />
        <span>Foo</span>
</label>
```

With the following SCSS:

```
.customCheckboxLabel {
  span {
    font-size: 3em;
    padding-bottom: 2px; //This is ignored. 
  }
  .customCheckboxInput {
    appearance: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance:none;
    width: 3em;
    height: 3em;
    background-color: transparent;
    border: 2px solid red;
    border-radius: 0.5em;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    &:checked {
      transform: rotate(45deg);
      border-color: black;
      &::after {
        content: "\2022";
        font-size: 6em;
        color: #41b883;
        text-align: center;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        line-height: 0.1em; //This is random
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This results in a circle appearing when the box is checked, that is not quite centred within its containing square. I have been able to approximately centre it using `line-height` set to random values, but this value must be changed for every checkbox height/width, and after element font size. This doesn't really work for what I need. What I really want, is for the only size definition to be the font-size of the span, and the width/height of the checkbox. The after-element should simply fill the checkbox (with a small amount of padding) and be centred

Additionally, I've been trying to add a bit of padding to the bottom of the span, but this is totally ignored. I just want the span and the checkbox to be vertically aligned.

Comment: DId you try about `line-height: 0.47em` or it's not exactly what you need?

Comment: @Azametzin As I said, I can dial it in for a specific checkbox size (by experimentation), but I'm looking for a way to explicitly put it in the centre, so that it doesn't need to be recalibrated every time the checkbox size is changed.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for creating a centralized circle, in this case, would be to make it different using background-color, positioning, relative dimensions, auto margin and border-radius.

```css
&::after {
  content: '';
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: auto;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #41b883;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```